# Facebook chatbot doesn't reply reviewer in app-review

Tags: chatbot, facebook-chatbot, facebook-app-requests, facebook-webhooks

We have made a chatbot for Facebook Messenger and submitted it for app review 2 times requesting pages_messaging. Both times the same error occurs:

The app reviewer presses "Get Started" and the bot greets the user, and asks a yes/no question - as it should. However, when the app reviewer responds to this question the bot never replies. As shown in picture 1.
In picture 2 it is shown how the bot responds to everybody else (we have tested with 9 users).

Does anybode know why the bot only replies once? There is no error code from the server logs.

We have applied for pages_messaging, and added the reviewers as testers of the app, and editor of the connected page. Have anybode else had a similar experience?

**Picture 1:**

[image]

**Picture 2:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Which framework you have used to develop your chatbot ? Can you cross check configuration while building your intent or entities, if you click on checkbox "Set this intent as end of discussion". If yes, please turn it off.